# Git doesn't see new files after upgrading to OS X High Sierra

Tags: git, macos-high-sierra

Across multiple repositories, with no fancy sub repos or anything, when I make a new file Git does not see it.

I can use `git status` and it shows nothing. I can use `git add .` and no files are staged. I have to manually add each and every file I create with `git add /path/to/file.extension`, but that works at least.

Yes, I know what you're thinking. No I don't have anything in my `.gitignore` files that would be causing this.

I upgraded to Git version `2.16.1`, and no dice. Same as before. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Git 2.16 has some (ongoing work) support for file system monitors to speed up the index-as-cache. I wonder if there's something botched there, so that it thinks that there's nothing to add because it has not seen a file system monitor event.

Answer (score 1):

> No I don't have anything in my .gitignore files that would be causing this.

Still: double-check that with

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/invisible/file
```

You will be sure that way if it is a .gitignore (or exclude or other global ignore file) issue.

> I can add the file without `--force`

Then check if the file was [not ignored with a `update-index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309):

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- a file
git update-index --no-skip-worktree -- a file
```

Check also or any `.gitattributes` file and their directives included in them.

Comment: Just curious: Would a .gitignore that ignores "git add ." allow a specific file to be added with "git add {filepath/name}"?

Comment: @Jazimov Only with `git add --force -- a/file/normally/ignored`

Comment: That gives me no output. And I can add the file without `--force`. Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Comment: Is it fair to say that if OP can add a file without --force then gitignore is not the culprit?

Comment: Then yes gitignore is not the issue here

Comment: @jpadvo I have edited the answer with another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you add a file and then run `git status`? I suspect that the `git` command you're running is operating from another folder and that's why it works when you use an explicit path. I'm on a Windows platform so I can't give OS-specific advice about Sierra but perhaps my suggestion might help... From where exactly are you running your git command--can you run your git command from the root path that contains your repo's hidden .git folder?

Comment: Can you also run 'git version' and let us know what you see (I want to be sure you're running what you think you're running)?